# Visual Studio 2013 debug hangs on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

Today I received a suite of Microsoft updates on my PC.  Following these updates, Chrome began *intermittently* hanging when I started debugging in Visual Studio 2013.  I have Windows 8.1 Enterprise, 64-Bit, and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with Update 4.  On my workstation, Chrome is version 39.0.2171.95 m.

Debugging via F5 or Ctrl+F5 (start without debugging) makes no difference, Chrome still intermittently hangs. This occurs on multiple web application projects, and even with one that is not connected to any external database.  Visual Studio 2013 works fine when I debug with Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Safari.  One of the sites is set up in IIS locally on my workstation, and I can successfully browse to the site in Chrome.  But if I launch that same site via Visual Studio 2013, the browser just hangs.  I cleared history and cookies in Chrome.  Rebooting doesn't correct this.

What's especially annoying about this is that the problem is intermittent.  If I cycle through several browsers in the Visual Studio debugger, on occasion Chrome will work.  In the past it's always worked.  Given that my PC received about 30 updates today, I suspect the problem is tied to one of those changes.

Is anyone else experiencing this Chrome problem in Visual Studio 2013, and if so what is the fix?  Thanks.

=== Edit 1/9/2015 ===

After troubleshooting this further I'm able to consistently replicate the issue, and now have a *workaround* for Chrome.  I've been running Visual Studio as an Administrator (elevated mode).

To replicate this do the following:

1. Run Visual Studio 2013 as an Administrator.
2. Close all instances of Chrome.
3. Select the Chrome browser in the Visual Studio ribbon and launch the site.
4. Chrome will hang indefinitely.

By comparison, you can follow the above steps for other browsers (IE, Firefox, and Safari), and they will successfully work without hanging.

There are two workarounds.  The first:  Avoid running Visual Studio 2013 as an Administrator, and you will be able to successfully launch Chrome from VS.  Here are steps for the second workaround.

1. Run Visual Studio as an Administrator.
2. Open an instance of Chrome *before* you launch the site in Visual Studio.
3. The site should successfully open.

My theory is that when Visual Studio attempts to launch a new browser instance, if it detects that Chrome is not running, it tries to launch Chrome in elevated mode.  And this causes Chrome to hang.  That's just my theory.  Someone with more knowledge about the internal workings of Visual Studio or Chrome will have more insight into this.

Note, this is a *workaround*. I don't consider it a solution, because this just addresses functionality that used to work.

Comment: untill recently it has always worked for me but now I face the same issue after doing some updates.. running in elevated mode doesn't help.
I got chrome working by using another browser and then opening the webpage on Chrome, but then it lacks the debug function.
If you have the answer please let me know.

Comment: @Andre Haverdings When I find out I'll post the solution. Just tweeted some Microsoft folks.

Comment: Yes, I experienced it too!  My setup: VS2013 Ultimate Update 4, Windows8.1. Chrome Version 41.0.2272.89 m.  For me, at the moment, Firefox appears to be ok.

Comment: I don't experience a hang, but I have noticed that once I debug in Chrome using VS2013, I can't open any links via external app (ie: Lync/Skype, email, etc) until I close all instances of Chrome.  Likewise, shift+left-clicking the icon in the task bar (which normally opens a new instance) does not work.  Also, clicking Chrome in the start menu doesn't work.  The only way to open a new instance of Chrome is to close all instances or open a new tab on the existing window.

Comment: This is happening to me too. Online on one machine.. lol.

Comment: My workaround is opening chrome and then start debugging, it just opens a new tab with my webapp.

Answer (score 2):

I too experienced it however I found a solution like open only single tab in chrome to debug, as soon as you close other tabs, vs will start running smooth.